# Ruby json parse error: unexpected token

Tags: ruby, json

I have a working method that opens and parses a json file. Now I'm trying to iterate through a directory of json files and display their contents.

Working method for a single file:

```
def aperson
  File.open("people/Elvis Presley.json") do |f|
    parse = JSON.parse(f.read) 
  end
end
```

Non-working method to iterate through a directory:

```
16. def list
17.   Dir.glob('people/*').each do |f|
18.     parse = JSON.parse(f) 
19    end
20. end
```

My error is:

```
/Users/ad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse': 743: unexpected token at 'people/Elvis Presley.json' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /Users/ad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
    from app.rb:18:in `block in list'
    from app.rb:17:in `each'
    from app.rb:17:in `list'
    from app.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

All of the files in the directory have the same content and are valis as per JSONlint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tried to parse the *filename* as JSON, which won't work.

Instead, you need to read the file first:

```
parse = JSON.parse(File.read(f))
```

Comment: Thanks but instead of getting the content of each file I get a listing of the files:                                                            people/Anthony DeFreitas.json
people/Elvis Presley.json
people/Seth Godin.json
people/Steve McQueen.json

Comment: Well, you need to *do something* with the result of `parse`. Otherwise, you're just going to get the result from `Dir.glob` (which is the list of filenames). Maybe you wanted to append the parsed data to a list?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I wrote the code wrong as I wanted to display the contents of each file and not just the file names. Thanks for your help nneonneo.

Answer (score 4):

not sure, but can you try to parse the content of file instead of file name:

```
parse = JSON.parse( File.read f )
```

Comment: `"people/#{f}"` won't exist; `f` already contains the expanded filename. But yeah, he's trying to read a filename and not the file contents.

Comment: Your revised solution is identical to the code that doesn't work.

Comment: My goal is to read the contents of each file, sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your non-working code, `f` is just string of the expanded file name. So you need to read the file after you've received the filename in the block.

While writing it, @nneonneo already gave you solution. So I'm not giving again.